# Trouble converting exponent equation into Java code

Tags: java, equation

I need to convert `a=n×s^2` into Java. My code looks something like this:

```
public float ABC( float n , float s)
{
  a = n*s;
  return a*a;
}
```

However if i print this out it returns the following error:

```
This method must return a result of type float
```

because of this I don't think my solution is correct. Would anyone be able to offer any solutions? I'm very new to Java.

Comment: It should be: `float a = n * s`, you forgot the type...

Comment: It normal math precendence rules, `a=n×s^2` is to be interpreted as: `a = n * s * s`, not `a = (n * s) * (n * s)`. Your attempt + all the answers so far are picking the exotic second interpretation. This sounds like all you need is `return n * s * s;` and you're making this way too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the type of the variable `a`:

```
public static float ABC( float n , float s) {
    float a = n * s;
    return a * a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the type for `a`, and since you are not using any instance variables, you can make the method `static`.

Furthermore, you could pass the result to `Math.pow` and cast the resulting `double` to a `float`.

```java
public class Question64613567 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(abc(2, 3));  // 36.0
        System.out.println(abc2(2, 3)); // 36.0
    }
     
    public static float abc(float n, float s) {
        float a = n * s;
        return a * a;
    }
    
    public static float abc2(float n, float s) {
        return (float) Math.pow(n * s, 2);
    }
}
```